# Correct React way to build a component with 100vw horizontally adjacent sections

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, carousel

I'm making a React app where one of my components is a parent to two other components, both styled as horizontally adjacent `100vw` sections. Only one section is visible at a time and the other is clipped by `overflow:hidden`, in every section there's also a button that allows the user to swap between them.

Here's a simplified version of the code I wrote to make it work:

```
import {useRef} from "react;
import ComponentB from "./ComponentB";
import ComponentC from "./ComponentC";

function ComponentA() {
    const containerRef = useRef();

    function changeSection() {
        containerRef.current.style.transform === ""
            ? (containerRef.current.style.transform = "translateX(-100vw)")
            : (containerRef.current.style.transform = "");
    }

    return (
        <main style={{ overflow: "hidden" }}>
            <div ref={containerRef} style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                <ComponentB changeSection={changeSection} />
                <ComponentC changeSection={changeSection} />
            </div>
        </main>
    );
}
```

Generally it works and so far I haven't found it to cause bugs or break the app in any way, but I'm not sure if it's the "correct" React way to implement such a feature. It kinda feels more like a vanilla javascript way of getting things done and as far as I know typical js solutions can sometimes backfire in React.
I'm looking for the simplest possible solution since I only need it for small devices - on bigger screens I can simply style my Components differently and fit everything on one screen.

My question is: what would be the correct approach to this in React?